# Yii2 : Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id

Tags: php, yii2

Выдает такую ошибку

> Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id

Вот код самого `action`:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

Как можно пофиксить?

Comment: выслать в action - id ?)

Comment: @Moonvvell можно подробнее(неделю только с php работаю)?

Comment: Missing required parameters: id -> говорит что не хватает обязательного параметра id ) С Yii не работал, как и с фреймворками, но должно быть ссылка по типу /view/25 (где 25 - id ) либо /view/id/25 либо /view?id=25. Это же ошибка в браузере когда пробуете открыть страницу ?)

Comment: по какому url эта ошибка возникает?

Comment: @AntonRybalko `http://a1/web/index.php?r=prod%2Fview`

Comment: @cruim наверное, нужно открывать http://a1/web/index.php?r=prod/view&id=1

Comment: работал с локальной таблицей, у которой не было pk. добавив его все заработало. всем спасибо за участие)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если параметр не всегда используется или на старте он равен 0 то можно так

```
public function actionView($id = 0)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему в вашем  URL не хватает параметра id. Должно быть что-то вроде http://a1/web/index.php?r=prod%2Fview%2F1
или если заменить %2F на / то http://a1/web/index.php?r=prod/view/1 
Где 1 это id товара.